# calling javascript function with c# WebBrowser

Tags: javascript, c#, html, web-scraping

I have some site that I'm trying to scrape its html code.

the site looks like this:

```
==combo box==

==== requseted page ===
```

when selecting option in the combobox the page content is changed.
I would like to get the current html code after the reload is done.

this is how the combobox is defined:

```
<select name="ddlVersion" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ddlVersion\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="ddlVersion" style="height:29px;width:295px;">
    <option selected="selected" value="1.htm"> 1 </option>
    <option value="2.htm"> 2 </option>
    <option value="3.htm"> 3 </option>
    </select>
```

__doPostBack in the HTML code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

and here is my code:

```
WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser();
htmlCode = Scrapper.getHtmlCodeAsString();
web.Document.Write(htmlCode);
web.Refresh();

var element = web.Document.GetElementById("ddlVersion");
element.SetAttribute("selectedIndex", "2");
element.InvokeMember("onchange");
```

I also tried:

```
WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser();
web.Document.Write(htmlCode);
web.Refresh();

var element = web.Document.GetElementById("ddlVersion");
element.SetAttribute("selectedIndex", "2");
web.Document.InvokeScript("__doPostBack");
```

Comment: hi, did you find any solution for this issue... or any workout to fix it?

Comment: nope. I just used other techniques to achieve my goal..